# Assign type from key of a Interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a interface:

```
interface IReceipt {
  payment: IPayment;
  details: string;
}
```

I have one component which takes payment as parameter:

```
const renderPayment = (props: {paymentInfo}) => {}
```

I need to define the type of paymentInfo as Payment. How can I use the IReceipt interface to assign type to `paymentInfo`

Something like `{paymentInfo: IReceipt.payment}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
paymentInfo: IReceipt['payment']
```

So you can simply write:

```
interface IReceipt {
    payment: IPayment;
    details: string;
}
const renderPayment = (props: {paymentInfo: IReceipt['payment']}) => {}
```

Comment: Minor suggestion. Create an enum and use it instead of string. That would be better as value of string can be anything

Comment: @Rajesh the details is a complete interface, I added string just for hiding extra details. But Thanks